# Is Boost using legal C++ preprocessing directive syntax?

Tags: c++, boost, syntax, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

My (relatively old) C++ compiler choked on [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/preprocessor/tuple/eat.hpp) file in Boost, which starts out as:

```
# /* Copyright (C) 2001
#  * Housemarque Oy
#  * http://www.housemarque.com
#  *
#  * Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See
#  * accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
#  * http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
#  */
#
```

Is this really legal C++? What's the rule on the syntax of preprocessor tokens?

Comment: Oh no! Don't tell me you use Turbo C++ too!!

Comment: @CodyGray: Heavens, no! It was an old VC compiler.

Comment: What version, VC 4.0? I'm curious why can't you upgrade

Comment: @Viet: 6.0. It was just a compatibility test for a library; I've already upgraded.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, a line containing only `#` and whitespace is explicitly permitted by the standard §16 [cpp]:

> control-line:
>      `# include` pp-tokens new-line
>      `# define` identifier replacement-list new-line
>      `# define` identifier lparen identifier-list<sub>opt</sub>`)` replacement-list new-line
>      `# define` identifier lparen `... )` replacement-list new-line
>      `# define` identifier lparen identifier-list`, ... )` replacement-list new-line
>      `# undef` identifier new-line
>      `# line` pp-tokens new-line
>      `# error` pp-tokens<sub>opt</sub> new-line
>      `# pragma` pp-tokens<sub>opt</sub> new-line
>      **`#` new-line**

Note that comments are replaced by whitespace at translation phase 3, that is before the preprocessor.

Comment: +1. The last one is all that I was looking for, and actually answers the question : `# new-line`.

Comment: @Nawaz: the OP asks "What's the rule on the syntax of preprocessor tokens" so providing some context won't hurt.

Comment: @Nawaz: Haha take a look at the edit history on my post, it was amusing. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Haha.. we were doing the same thing at the same time, hence SO merged them.

Comment: Why is boost commenting and adding blank preprocessor token? Is there any advantage in doing that instead of using just simple regular block comment?

Comment: @LieRyan: look at the file linked in question. The author decided that it is easier to start *all* lines in the file with `#`. It's just such a coding style. Personally I don't like it.